# Contract job vs Employment on Resume

Tags: resume, recruitment

From the perspective of a prospective employee, what is the difference between being onsite with another firm (from your parent organization) and a contract position for that firm?

For instance there's a company 'A' that recruits an employee and offers to send them on-site to a company 'B'(that is relatively of higher reputation than 'A'), is that equivalent to a contract position employment? How would either reflect on the employee in terms of career prospects?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Do you want to know the legal differences, how it will be seen from the point of view of company 'B', what to put on a resume later on? Please do expand on the question you have a bit, as this might get closed other wise.

Comment: Please find the re edits. I hope I make more sense now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this appears to be about the legal rules involved which unfortunately we're not able to help you with.

Comment: I wouldnt know if there is some definition difference in industrial parlance between the usage of these 2 terms "on-site" and "contract". Well if one calls that legal rule then may be.

Comment: At least here in germany, this is commonly used to differenciate between being employed at company 'A' which lends you to company 'B' to do work there and being self-employed, contracting for company 'B'. You'll be doing the same work, but all legal as well as contractual aspects differ.

Comment: Ahmm okay that fairly explains. Though i wonder which one would weigh better in terms of career prospects and adding value to resume.

Comment: I've tried an edit, to elicit answers about this. Please feel free to roll back if you disagree or [edit] some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been in this situation a few times.

If company (A) sends you to company (B), the following things may occur:

1. You may receive a cheque directly from Company A
2. Company B may not know how well you are compensated
3. Only very rarely, your placement at that company may be confidential

Unless your placement is secret, you can totally list on your resume, or your LinkedIn, that you worked at whichever of the companies you wish. You can even list both, since you did technically work for both.

For example, Company A, RecruitoCo, hires you, and sends you immediately to work at respected developer DevTech.

You get a cheque from RecruitCo, but on a day-to-day basis you work for people at DevTech. So who do you say you work for? Barring any contractual provisions, you can identify as working for either. Whatever suits you best.

Legally, you are bound by any covenants of secrecy that are within your contract, so I'd advise you to look at it, if any particular detail concerns you.

Source: Worked this way since 2013.

Comment: Precisely matches my circumstance. Thanks for sharing.